# Apache CXF SearchContext for FIQL with custom data dictionary

Tags: apache, cxf

I want to use CXF to parse FIQL as per the standard mechanism. However, I do not want to use a JAXB-encoded object but rather a custom data dictionary source. Here's an example of the "normal" way:

```
@Path("book")
@GET
public List<Book> findBooks(@Context SearchContext searchContext) {
    SearchCondition<Book> condition = searchContext.getCondition(Book.class);
    return condition.findAll(theBooks);
}
```

Here, if my understanding is right, Book must be a java bean, with individual properties that correspond to the search expression elements. So if I have:

```
public class Book {
  String title;
  String asin;
}
```

I could do a query like:

```
GET /book?_s=asin==B00NAIMGXI
```

and return the matching rows. This is fine, but I cannot create individual bean classes like Book. In fact, I have a large dynamic data dictionary (DBSchema) and I want to be able to do queries against anything in that schema. I can't find any way to do that, though.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some quality time with the source code I found that if you pass a class called SearchBean, like so:

```
SearchCondition<SearchBean> searchCondition = searchContext.getCondition(SearchBean.class);
```

your FIQL expression can have any arbitrary names. I don't know how official this capability is - it's not in the JAX-RS guide, but it does appear in [this jira issue CXF-4314](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4314), so I'm guessing (hoping?) it's considerd part of the public interface of CXF.

Comment: D'oh. Turns out this is mentioned in the doc and I missed it.